# please explain how to solve this question which is a question pertained to infinity raised to the power 0

Tags: integration, limits, logarithms

[image]

I tried taking log and then converting it into definite integral but i was not able to convert the left part of the question into (r/n) form, please help

Comment: Is any of the answers below helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I show you how to get the Riemann sums:
\begin{align}
n^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}\cdot\left(1^1\cdot2^2\cdot\ldots n^n\right)&=\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\ln(n)\right]\cdot\exp\left[\frac{1}{n^2}\ln\left(\prod_{k=1}^nk^k\right)\right]\\
%
&=\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\ln(n)+\frac{1}{n^2}\ln\left(\prod_{k=1}^nk^k\right)\right]\\
%
&=\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\ln(n)+\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(k^k\right)\right]\\
%
&=\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\ln(n)+\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^nk\ln\left(k\right)\right]\\
%
&=\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\ln(n)+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n}\ln\left(\frac{k}{n}\cdot n\right)\right]\\
%
&=\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\ln(n)+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}{n}\ln\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)+\frac{k}{n}\ln(n)\right)\right].
\end{align}
Now use that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n}\ln\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}\int_0^1 x\ln(x)\mathrm{d}x,\\
%
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n}\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}\int_0^1 x\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
to simplify the term $-\frac{1}{2}\ln(n)$ (take care of the first order term when you take the limit of the Riemann sums above: you must control the term $\ln(n)$ with a $\mathcal{O}_{n\to+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$). I let you fill the details.

Answer (score 0):

*Another solution (using logarithms).*

$$\prod_{k=1}^n k^k=H(n)$$ where $H(.)$ is the [hyperfactorial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Hyperfactorial). So
$$a_n=n^{-\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)} \big[H(n)\big]^{\frac{1}{n^2}}$$
$$\log(a_n)=-\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\log(n)+\frac{1}{n^2}\log\big[H(n)\big]$$ Using Stirling-like approximations
$$\log\big[H(n)\big]=n^2 \left(\frac{\log (n)}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)+\frac{1}{2} n \log (n)+\log \left(A
   \sqrt[12]{n}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ where $A$ is Glaisher constant.

So
$$\log(a_n)=-\frac 14+\frac{12 \log (A)+\log (n)}{12 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)=-\frac 14+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ $$a_n=e^{\log(a_n)}=e^{-\frac 14}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

If you use the expansion to $O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$ and take the exponential of it, for $n=2$ the relative error is $0.00840$% and for $n=3$ it is $0.00169$%.